# Char Sequence comparison in two strings using LINQ

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have two strings say:-
string s1 = "TEST";
string s2 = "ASDTFGHEJKLSIOPT";

Now if we have a close look on the sequence of characters from string s1 in string s2, we find that s2 contains all characters from s1 in the same sequence but with different index.

I want a solution (using LINQ if possible or with minimum complexity array solution), that return true if a string contains all characters from another string in same sequence irrespective of their indexes else it should return false.

Comment: `I want a solution ...` and a coffee while we are working on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
string s1 = "TEST"; string s2 = "ASDTFGHEJKLSIOPT";
//Will return all the matching characters without loosing their sequence
var matchingString = new string(s2.Where(r => s1.Contains(r)).ToArray());
if (matchingString.Contains(s1))
{
    //found
}
else
{
    //not found
}
```

This will make sure if the matching string contains the `s1` in the same sequence, irrespective of the index.

Answer (score 0):

The Linq [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549218%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method can be used for this purpose:

```
public static class TextHelper
{
    public static bool ContainsInterspersed(this string outer, string inner)
    {
        if (outer == null || inner == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return ((IEnumerable<char>)inner).Aggregate(0, (nextIndex, ch) =>
            {
                nextIndex = (nextIndex < 0 ? nextIndex : outer.IndexOf(ch, nextIndex));
                if (nextIndex >= 0)
                    nextIndex++;
                return nextIndex;
            }) >= 0;
    }
}
```

This is linear in the length of the two strings.  No arrays or substrings are created by this method.